# Changing values on web page before scraping it

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape the following page using JSoup:

https://basketballmonster.com/PlayerRankings.aspx

But before scraping the page, I'd like to change the value of "Past Games" to 5, and select "All Players" instead of "Top Players".

I've been able to scrape plenty of pages with JSoup without issue, but I'm having trouble finding any information on how to change the values on the page before doing the scraping. I've done a lot of googling and nothing seems to return what I need.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done or even give the proper terminology for what it is I'm trying to do?

The following is the gist of the scraping code, but I have no clue how to update the page before the actual scrape:

```
String URL = "https://basketballmonster.com/PlayerRankings.aspx";

    try
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

        Elements table = doc.getElementsByClass("dataTable");

        for (Element row : table.select("tr"))
        {
             //Split rows into objects
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please, [read _how to ask good questions_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GillesQuenot Can you tell me what the specific problem is with this question is?  It's hard to be more specific when I don't know the terminology for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: SO is for asking about problem about your attempts of code, we don't see anything there

Comment: @GillesQuenot Well the the welcome e-mail I got said "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."  This is a question about programming.

Comment: @GillesQuenot If there's a more appropriate forum to ask this question on, let me know.  It seems like it's a pretty specific programming question to me.

Comment: You've hit a bit of a grey area. A quick search turned up [this meta post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311246) that discusses the very same thing. It is probably OK to ask a "how to do" question if the answer is short, **and not easily searchable**. If the answer is a reasonable amount of code then the question is off-topic as *Too Broad*. Here is the crux of the issue: if you don't know what the answer will be, you won't know if the question is too broad or not. The other thing to do is to always include any appropriate code (see [mcve] for tips), so context/effort can be seen.

Comment: Oh, and *"provide any related learning material"* is definitely off-topic. See point #4 in [help/on-topic]. I've removed it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

JSoup is not a browser, it is a simple HTML parser library. Changing the values you mention via DOM manipulation will not do what you want. I assume by ' change the value of "Past Games" to 5' you mean that you want to retrieve the HTML that the server sends to the browser when doing these changes in a browser, right?

In order to achieve what you want you must analyze how the website operates. I had a quick look and found that when you change the "Past Games" to 5 a POST request is triggered. Look in the develope's tool of your browser to see that.

JSoup is perfectly able to send such a post request to the webserver and receive the result HTML. This should contain what you want.

So read about how to put together POST requests in JSoup and analyze what parameters the webserver needs to be fed. This should lead you to success.